# Assignment Order in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Something I don't get in the following snippet:
a and b are now pointers to the same object.

```
var foo = {n:1}; /// foo points to an object
var bar = foo;  /// bar point to the same object as foo
foo.x = foo = {n:2};  /// foo is now pointing to a new object
```

In the last assignment, property x is added to bar.
Why? Shouldn't x point to n:2?

Answer (score 0):

```
foo.x = foo = {n:2};  /// foo is now pointing to a new object
```

you can simplify as

```
foo = {n:2}; // foo point to a NEW object
foo.x = foo;
```

so x is point to foo. property link to itself object.

Comment: If I run this as script in Chrome, it appears that bar has new property.                                                                                         foo: Object
n: 2

bar: Object
n: 1
x: Object

foo.x: undefined

Comment: This answer is wrong.